# jquery-ias - IASHistoryExtension + prev button styling

Tags: jquery, ias

Thanks for an awsome plugin. 
I truly appreciate the back button functionality. However I have some issues that I would love to see solved. In my theme I have a need to target the generated next and prev links individually. Rigth now they receive the same class and behavior. Is there a way to generate a specific class for the prev button?
The alternative would be to load all previous pages when returning from itemA to the list page, thus eliminating the need for the prev button. Is that something that's doable?

Cheers
Mikael

Answer (score -1):

IAS does not generate a next and prev link. You have to do that yourself server-side. You are free to use any class you like for the prev element.